# Indexer in C# but without this

Tags: c#, indexer

It is posible to craete indexer in C#, but something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
   Dictionary<int, string> myCollection = new Dictionary<int, string>();

   public string Value[int i]
   {
      get { return myCollection[i]; }
      set { myCollection[i] = value; }
   }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried running the code yourself? what does it do? does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `C#` do not allows this.

Specification section 1.6.7.3 saying:

> An indexer is a member that enables objects to be indexed in the same
>   way as an array. An indexer is declared like a property except that
>   the name of the member is this followed by a parameter list written
>   between the delimiters [ and ].

I would suggest you to use simple method for this like:

```
public string GetValue(int key)
{
    if (dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
       .....
}
```

In your case you reffer dictionary items by `key` not an `index`, this is pretty defferent things.

**PS:** keep in mind that Dictionary does not persist order of the items and this could be vital for some cases!

Answer (score 1):

No,

Actually your property `Value` already have indexer from string and returns char. Probably you need something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
   Dictionary<int, string> myCollection = new Dictionary<int, string>();

   public Dictionary<int, string> Value
   {
      get { return myCollection; }
      set { myCollection = value; }
   }
}
```

And it will be the behaviour what you expected.

```
string value = myClassInstance.Value[0];
```

Comment: +1, but probably better to expose an IDictionary interface, and drop the setter :)

Comment: Yes but I don't want to return all dictionary, because this will be allowed too: myClassInstance.Value.Add(...), and this dictionary can include only 3 values, and other user cannot adding other values

Comment: So, as an option you can: 1) create type with indexed and incapsulate dictionary in it (if you very want index); 2) Change property to methor `GetValue(int key)`;

Comment: Ok I will do like this:

    public int Currenti { get; set; }

    
    public string Value
       {
          get { return myCollection[Currenti]; }
          set { myCollection[Currenti] = value; }
       }

Comment: In that case I'd recommend calling them CurrentIndex and CurrentValue

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it that way, (not supported by C#)

How about instead

```
public class MyClass
{
   public MyClass()
    {
          Values = new Dictionary<int, string>()
     }
      public Dictionary<int, string> Values { get; set }   
}
```

which will then allow you to do

```
MyClass foo = new MyClass();
var someVal = foo.Values[3];
```